# python simpleHTTPServer woking only with local machine

Tags: 14.04, networking, python

I ran following command to run http server

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

and get following message

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

but i am not able to access it on another machine/mobile in local wifi network, i tried accessing it from my local machine and able to access it.

please lemme know if anyone able to figure out what's the problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually web server work on `port 80`. Your http server work on `port 8000`, because of that try in browser to access with address `http://ip_address:8000`

Comment: that's what i tried man but it's saying unable to connect.

Answer (score 10):

`SimpleHTTPServer` by default binds to the ip address `0.0.0.0`. This is a special address meaning in effect "any address". If it were to bind to for example `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, you could only connect to it from the local machine, because `127.0.0.1` belongs to the [loopback device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/what-is-the-loopback-interface). But with `0.0.0.0`, the server's binding to `lo`, `eth0` and any other network devices you might have.

So, your little server *should* be reachable from other machines in your network. That it is not indicates that something (other than your little server) prohibits it, maybe a firewall. You could check the state of port 8000 with `nmap` from another machine (you might need to install `nmap`). Say your little server is running on ip 192.168.0.1, the other machine is 192.168.2.101. Then you'd do from 192.168.2.101

```
nmap -p 8000 192.168.0.1
```

The output should be something like

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8000/tcp open  http-alt
```

If the state is "open", the port is reachable and there's something listening there, so your little server should be reachable.

If the state is "closed", the port is reachable, but there's nothing listening there. In that case, maybe your server has terminated or you mixed up ip or port numbers.

If the state is "filtered", there's some kind of ip filtering firewall at play that keeps you from accessing your little server.

Comment: status is open still am not able to access it from my phone.

Comment: Have you checked with `nmap` from your phone? Is your phone part of your local network (via WiFi, for example)? Or is, as far as your local network is concerned, your phone "somewhere outside", maybe in your phone provider's network? Can you access the server from another machine in your network, aside from your phone? It looks like a networking problem to me.

Comment: dude i also try from other machine within local network but i am not able to access.

Comment: I can only assume that something in your network is blocking your access. A firewall, a proxy, some kind of content filter, anything.  But I could only guess what it might be. The server command itself works fine on my test server.

Comment: Another issue I'm seeing sometimes is that when docker is installed, `0.0.0.0` binding actually doesn't work (outside of localhost). I fix this by binding to the machine's ip address that the server is running on (e.g. something like `192.168.1.24`).

Answer (score 3):

After you start the SimpleHTTPServer with: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`,

You need to find out your server's IP address, within your local network, on your terminal using:

linux/mac: `ifconfig`
windows: `ipconfig`

Then on your mobile device try to reach `ip_address:PORT`,
e.g.: `192.168.1.5:8000`